# Efficient way to clean rare inputs

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I want to replace some rare inputs with others, i.e. my process will 'clean' the input in some way. My current solution for this is to override `dict.__getitem__` and maintain a small dictionary of the exceptions (a few dozen at most).

```
class RDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        dict.__init__(self, args)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key):
        except KeyError:
            return key
```

But this feels ugly, firstly because I am using an exception in the 'normal' case, but secondly because it seems like a code heavy way of achieving a fairly simple effect. I tried `defaultdict` from `collections`, but that takes a parameterless function, i.e. the default cannot depend on the input item, only on some, potentially non-strict, function call. N.B. I am looking for a general solution, not one that is type (e.g. string) specific.

(I solved my own problem whilst composing the question, but I am still posting because I am curious if there is a built-in, standard, or just particularly neat/efficient way of doing this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to just use the dictionary, which has the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method for just such occasions, directly:

```
DIRTY.get(x, x)
```

---

Based on your comment, I did a quick test with `timeit`:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def dict_get_direct(d, x):
    return d.get(x, x)

>>> def dict_get_manual(d, x):
    if x in d:
        return d[x]
    return x

>>> timeit.timeit("dict_get_direct({1:2, 3:4}, 1)", setup="from __main__ import dict_get_manual, dict_get_direct")
0.48331750281312225
>>> timeit.timeit("dict_get_direct({1:2, 3:4}, 5)", setup="from __main__ import dict_get_manual, dict_get_direct")
0.45923153755705926
>>> timeit.timeit("dict_get_manual({1:2, 3:4}, 1)", setup="from __main__ import dict_get_manual, dict_get_direct")
0.45144323770750816
>>> timeit.timeit("dict_get_manual({1:2, 3:4}, 5)", setup="from __main__ import dict_get_manual, dict_get_direct")
0.40186868623015926
>>> timeit.timeit("{1:2, 3:4}.get(1, 1)", setup="from __main__ import dict_get_manual, dict_get_direct")
0.3100665514014622
>>> timeit.timeit("{1:2, 3:4}.get(5, 5)", setup="from __main__ import dict_get_manual, dict_get_direct")
0.2964287294703354
```

I see similar performance for the two functions (the "manual" version is slightly faster, especially with all misses), but clearly if you can inline the `dict.get` rather than call a function it's much faster.

Comment: Interestingly, having just tried this, it is slightly slower than the clean function. I suspect it's an artefact of how frequently / infrequently it fails. I will do more research. Thanks

Comment: @jhoyla Updated with quick `timeit` tests.

Comment: Your point about inlining is true for both the manual and direct versions. `DIRTY[x] if x in DIRTY else x` is almost two times faster than `DIRTY.get(x,x)`.

Comment: @jhoyla yes, I get similar results (0.079 vs 0.168) in the all-misses case, albeit similar performance (0.110 vs 0.155) for the all-hits case.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst writing this question two solutions came to me (or rather one solution that can be used to improve my former solution). 
The obvious method for doing this is

```
def clean(x):
    if x in DIRTY:
        return DIRTY[x]
    return x
```

But if I want a dictionary-like interface then

```
class RDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        dict.__init__(self, args)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key):
        return key
```

turns out to be more than twice as fast as my original suggestion (albeit three times slower than the clean function).